# IE7 text-align:right not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, text-align

I have a h3 and an h1 tag:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="title">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
        <h3>Title1</h3>
        <h1><a href="#">Title2</a></h1>
    </div><!-- end .title -->
</div><!-- end #header -->

#header {
 background: transparent url(images/header_bg.png) top center no-repeat;
 margin: 30px auto 0;
 width: 960px;
 height: 240px;
}
#header .title { float: right }
#header h1,
#header h2,
#header h3 {
 text-align: right;
 border: none;
 padding: 0;
}
```

In IE7, the h3 aligns right like it's supposed to, but the h1 doesn't.  WHY?

Comment: what is the display property of h1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify an explicit width for `.title div` - You should use the IE developer tools (press F12) to solve these kind of problems.

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233683/how-to-deal-with-ie7-not-determining-the-width-of-floated-items-correctly) similar question

Comment: Thanks so much, @Perfect Dark.  That solution checks out!